# Strange SATA Problem / Ubuntu 14.04 / ASUS P8Z68V / OCZ Vertex 2

Tags: ssd, sata, ahci

this is my first question, because i usually got things going myself.
But this time i'm out of ideas.

As mentioned in the thread title, i have a very strange problem with my SATA boot device.

It happens now and then, i think every 2 or 3 months, that my system won't boot up. I then see only the cursor blinking after BIOS screen.

And today, this happend to occur while actually working with the PC. This led to the fact, that the system didn't have access to the SSD drive no more. You could imagine that i was presented with very weird system behaviour.

However, i have found out that when the problem arises, i have to reboot, go into UEFI setup, change the SATA mode from AHCI to IDE, reboot and the system comes up again. Interestingly, at the first boot, the system is very slow. But after the next boot it's getting fast again.

And now the strangest thing about it. After all that, i can go into UEFI setup again and change SATA back to AHCI and all is working again as usually.

What the... ? Should i replace the SSD drive?

Comment: Hmm ... I am trying to remember the circumstances when I had a similar behaviour. While I did not come up with the idea to alter the BIOS settings, I had to either power off the system and additionally plug off the SSD sometimes - not always. I am not quite sure, but it may be that this was the behaviour of my old 64 gb ssd that is dead now. So if your symptoms have a tendency to degrade, take into account the worst case. Just to make sure: your ssd is connected with a 6 gb/s cable? Because it can get really weird if the cable is slightly to slow.

Comment: Thanks. It is most likely no 6 gb/s cable. But actually this is an old 64 GB SSD too. So the Vertex 2 has an SATA 3Gbps interface. Yes, maybe i should replace it in advance.

Comment: Maybe it will be usable for non mission critical stuff, but not the operating system. Is this the Indilinx Barefoot controller on your device? If yes, this would match my old Supertalent.